# Novel in which alien (Martian?) is trapped on Earth in prehistory

Tags: story-identification, novel

What I seem to remember is that the Martian is stranded by the destruction of his civilization. Also, there is an odd detail that sticks in my brain: the Martian drops a bracelet (or a watch?) in a river, where the implication is that it could be found centuries later. The Martian may have intended to influence the development of humans. Quite poignant at the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like [Inherit the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giants_(series)) by James P. Hogan.

There is indeed a bracelet found at the end of that novel, which apparently belongs to an alien refugee cast away on an ancient earth.

Comment: I believe you are perfectly right. Very impressive. What a memory!

Comment: If my memory serves, the bracelet was stamped with the alien's name, Koriel